# Embed player on Facebook Wall

Tags: flash, facebook, mp3, embed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to embed a custom SWF based audio player into facebook wall posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997811/how-to-embed-a-custom-swf-based-audio-player-into-facebook-wall-posts)

I don't know how to do this so please help :)

I want to start posting mp3 links on my and other walls and at one point I saw someone do this and a mp3 player was embeded in facebook to play the audio. When I post a link all I get is the link people can click.

How do I:
1. make a flash playable on the FB wall via the clickable play thumbnail.
2. Make a mp3 playanle on the FB wall via the mp3 player fb uses.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook does this automatically for you if the link you post ends with .mp3. Try posting a link to a mp3 file and see :) It also works for sharing via facebook mail. Facebook also reads the artist and song title from the filename. Just seperate them with '-' like: artist-title.mp3

Hope this helps

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  I post a link to an MP3, no player shows up.  Just the link, in a box where one would expect the player to be.

I'm using Chrome, if that matters.

Comment: Yeah apparently they changed it. You might be able to achieve the same effect using the API but I am not sure.

Comment: nah you can no longer use their player