# How use the source tag and meta-tags of the facebook open graph API to display iframe with text/html?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, iframe

Know anybody the plattform ["SoundCloud"](https://soundcloud.com/), they have embeded the player as text/html page in a iframe.

Do anbody know how this works?

An Working example for the meta tags could you see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623865/playing-back-an-embedded-mp4-video-in-a-facebook-like-or-share-using-flash)