# share video link and play inline in facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, facebook-like

I tried Robs solution on [Playing back an embedded mp4 video in a Facebook like or share using Flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623865/playing-back-an-embedded-mp4-video-in-a-facebook-like-or-share-using-flash) but the video still could not play inline in facebook wall... If i change "og:video" to youtube or vimeo, it works perfectly... Can anyone figure this out? Thanks alot!

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="video system" /><meta property="og:url" content="http://video.system.com?video_id=11111" />
<meta property="og:title" content="the video title" /> 
<meta property="og:image" content="http://video.system.com/11111.jpg" /> 

<meta property="og:description" content="the video description" /> 

<meta property="og:type" content="video" />

<meta property="og:video" content="https://app.system.com/StrobeMediaPlayback.swf?flashvars=&src=https://app.system.com/11111.mp4" />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://app.system.com/StrobeMediaPlayback.swf?flashvars=&src=https://app.system.com/11111.mp4" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="320" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="180" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your og:video:type to "video/mp4"

```
    <meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4" data-content-type="dynamic">
```

Reference- somewhere on this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-custom-stories#propertytypes